# Example of (a|b)* about Alternation , I am confused , Why are ab, ba in the result set?

Tags: regex, alternation

Alternation is about Union, then if We have R={"a"} , S={"b"} , then R|S will be {"a", "b"}.

Why ab, ba are included there in (a|b)*?

I don't understand why

[image]
[image]

[Regular Expresion wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition)

I think the result set should be
(a|b)* = {Ɛ,"a", "b", "aa","bb", "aaa", "bbb", ...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `a|b` matches either `a` or `b`.

The expression `(a|b)*` matches for example `(a|b) (a|b) (a|b)`. In each of these alternatives, you can choose individually whether to match `a` or `b`. You don't have to choose the same for all of them.

The variant "either `a*` or `b*`" is written exactly as pronounced: `a*|b*`.

Comment: I didn't realize that (a|b) (a|b) (a|b), yes it is right. The asterisk quantifier take in this case  (a|b) and indicates zero or more occurrences of it.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, you can think of (a|b)* as

- (empty set) or
- (a|b) or
- (a|b)(a|b) or
- (a|b)(a|b)(a|b) ...

It's clear from this that the choice of a or b can alternate in the sequence. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`*` means zero or more, it's almost like you'd write:

```
(a|b)(a|b)(a|b)(a|b)(a|b)...
```

meaning it repeats pattern, not the text matched, so if it once matches `a` it doesn't have to match `a` again, because it repeats pattern `(a|b)`, so again, it wil match `a` or `b`.

That's why it can match any combination of `a`s and `b`s

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(a|b)*` uses an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either a OR b and repeat that 0+ times due to the [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `*`

There is [an example](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-tricks.html#staralt) to write `(a|b)*` without the alternation which might be helpfull to reason about it why you get those matches:

```
a*(?:b+a*)*
```

To only get consecutive matches instead of mixed ones you might use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\b(a|b)\1*\b` to repeat what has exactly being captured in the group. See a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gf0eyX/1).